# How to set Content Security Policy for Laravel bundle assets using spatie

Tags: laravel, policies, content-security-policy

I am using spatie/laravel-csp package for setting up CSP for my web app. I bundle my JS and call them in the layout this this.

```
@vite('resources/js/app.js')
```

Before bundling it was working fine but after bundling my assets I got errors from Spatie package These are the two errors

```
Refused to load the script 'http://[::1]:5173/@vite/client' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'nonce-h8NpfGFc7bxb1WLH74Mxzkoa3wMQ0umA' http://127.0.0.1:5173/resources/js/app.js". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

```
Refused to load the script 'http://[::1]:5173/resources/js/app.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'nonce-h8NpfGFc7bxb1WLH74Mxzkoa3wMQ0umA' http://127.0.0.1:5173/resources/js/app.js". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

This is my guest layout policy class

```
$this
            ->addDirective(Directive::STYLE, 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')
            ->addDirective(Directive::STYLE, 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2')
            ->addDirective(Directive::DEFAULT, 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2')
            ->addDirective(Directive::DEFAULT, 'https://fonts.gstatic.com/')
            ->addDirective(Directive::STYLE, 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/boxicons/2.1.0/css/boxicons.min.css')
            ->addDirective(Directive::DEFAULT, 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/')
            ->addDirective(Directive::IMG, 'data:');
```

How do I define policy for vite bundle?